# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list - Autoregressive models

Tags: python, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

Dears,
I am applying autoregressive models on a time series dataset when i am trying to fit the model, i am getting this error mentioned in the title.
please find below code.

```
dataset = dataset.values
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
print(len(train), len(test))

from matplotlib import pyplot
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

# train autoregression
model = AutoReg(train, lags=20)
model_fit = model.fit()
```

Error recieved:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-94515331b50e> in <module>
      1 # train autoregression
----> 2 model = AutoReg(train, lags=20)
      3 model_fit = model.fit()

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Please advise how to fix this.

Comment: I suspect something is fishy with your train dataset. It could be helpful to show some of it (top few rows) here, and for you to scan the whole thing to see if it looks like you would expect

Comment: Hi, How can i attach the dataset ?

Comment: sample output from train

Comment: array([[ 9.77781172e+01,  2.50000000e-01,  1.23322846e+02,
         1.13850000e+02,  8.72000000e+01],
       [ 1.10163345e+02, -6.60000000e+00,  9.49962845e+01,
         1.15420000e+02,  8.70000000e+01],
       [ 7.20595094e+01,  1.00100000e+01,  6.70275726e+01,
         1.16990000e+02,  8.69000000e+01],

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, would be good to see `dataset`. But this line

```
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], ...
```

makes me think that the dataset is two-dimensional, whereas the documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg.html) indicates that you need 1D

so perhaps you want

```
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,0], ...
```

or some other column (not index-0) of your dataset

Comment: How can i attach the dataset ?

Comment: copy and paste the first few rows, using markdown as you do for code

Comment: so indeed, looking at your dataset, as mentioned above, your train and test are 2D arrays whereas AutoReg expects 1D, so you should try the suggestion in this answer and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

so indeed, looking at your dataset, as mentioned above, your train and test are 2D arrays whereas AutoReg expects 1D, so you should try the suggestion in this answer and see if it works? – piterbarg